# Can't select current date in Foundation DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, datetimepicker

I am using this [foundation datepicker](https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker) component in one of my projects and it works but I can't select the current date and don't know what's wrong in my code. Here is the the code:

```
$(function() {

    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $('.dpicker').fdatepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }, 
        onChangeDate: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NCYuL/), any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of 'now' is dropping the hours from the time.  Create it in UTC.
Also,

```
return date.valueOf() <= now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
```

should be

```
return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
```

Here's a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/gL2A4/

Comment: Already tried that way and didn't work since I can't select the current date and if I select one day next to the current, current get disabled

Comment: Sorry, in retrospect, it looks like it's a time zone thing.
Date: Tue Oct 08 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) 
Now: Tue Oct 08 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

Comment: Did you notice that even with your fiddle you can't pick current date and if you pick next day then you can't even see current day active? So problem remains